# Count observations within dynamic range

Tags: stata

Consider the following example:

```
input group day month year number treatment NUM
1 1 2 2000 1 1 2
1 1 6 2000 2 0 .
1 1 9 2000 3 0 .
1 1 5 2001 4 0 .
1 1 1 2010 5 1 1
1 1 5 2010 6 0 .
2 1 1 2001 1 1 0
2 1 3 2002 2 1 0
end

gen date = mdy(month,day,year) 
format date %td
drop day month year
```

For each group, I have a varying number of observations. Each observations refers to an event that is specified with a date. Variable number is the numbering within each group.

**Now, I want to count the number of observations that occur one year starting from the date of each treatment observation (excluding itself) within this group.** This means, I want to create the variable NUM that I have already put into my example above. I do not care about the number of observations with treatment = 0.

**EDIT Begin**: The following information was found to be missing but necessary to tackle this problem: The treatment variable will have a value of 1 if there is no observation within the same group in the last year. Thus it is also not possible that the variable NUM will have to consider observations with treatment = 1. In principal, it is possible that there are two observations within a group that have identical dates. **EDIT End**

I have looked into [Stata tip 51: Events in intervals](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0033). It seems to work out however my dataset is huge (> 1 mio observations) such that it is really really inefficient - especially because I do not care about all treatment = 0 observations.

I was wondering if there is any alternative. My approach was to look for the observation with the latest date within each group that is still in the range of 1 year (and maybe store it in variable latestDate). Then I would simply subtract the value in variable number of the observation found from the value in count of the treatment = 0 variable.

**Note**: My "inefficient" code looks as follows

```
gsort -treatment
gen treatment_id = _n
replace treatment_id = . if treatment==0
gen count=.
sum treatment_id, meanonly
qui forval i = 1/`r(max)'{
        count if inrange(date-date[`i'],1,365) & group == group[`i']
        replace count = r(N) in `i'
}
sort group date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that treatment can't occur within 1 year of the previous treatment (in the group). This is true in your example data, but may not be true in general. But, assuming that it is the case, then this should work. I'm using `carryforward` which is on SSC (`ssc install carryforward`). Like your latestDate thought, I determine one year after the most recent treatment and count the number of observations in that window.

```
sort group date
gen yrafter = (date + 365) if treatment == 1
by group: carryforward yrafter, replace
format yrafter %td
gen in_window = date <= yrafter & treatment == 0
egen answer = sum(in_window), by(group yrafter)
replace answer = . if treatment == 0
```

I can't promise this will be faster than a loop but I suspect that it will be.

Comment: I think it works fine even if there is treatment within one year of the previous treatment.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the proper counting rules. If the next treatment (and any other observations) should count as an additional +1 in NUM, then it won't (I don't think, because the yrafter will stop carrying forward). But if that doesn't matter (or if the NUM rule is how many more before the next treatment and within a year), then you're right, it'll be fine.

Comment: I agree. That is my interpretation, at least. The original poster would have to clarify.

Comment: I am sorry for an imprecise explanation of my dataset! Let me fill the gap: The treatment variable will have a value of 1 if there is no observation within the last year and within the same group (as you already figured out). Thus it is also not possible that the variable NUM will have to consider observations with treatment = 1 - remember that NUM is supposed to exclude the observation which gives the starting point of the time frame. In principal, it is possible that there are two observations within a group that have identical dates. From my understanding all requirements are fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not completely clear.

Consider the following data with two different results, `num2` and `num3`:

```
  +-----------------------------------------+
  |     date2   group   treat   num2   num3 |
  |-----------------------------------------|
  | 01feb2000       1       1      3      2 |
  | 01jun2000       1       0      .      . |
  | 01sep2000       1       0      .      . |
  | 01nov2000       1       1      0      0 |
  | 01may2002       1       0      .      . |
  | 01jan2010       1       1      1      1 |
  | 01may2010       1       0      .      . |
  |-----------------------------------------|
  | 01jan2001       2       1      0      0 |
  | 01mar2002       2       1      0      0 |
  +-----------------------------------------+
```

The variable `num2` is computed assuming you are interested in counting **all** observations that are within a one-year period after a treated observation (`treat == 1`), be those observations equal to 0 or 1 for `treat`. For example, after 01feb2000, there are three observations that comply with the time span condition; two have `treat==0` and one has `treat == 1`, and they are all counted.

The variable `num3` is also counting observations that are within a one-year period after a treated observation, but only the cases for which `treat == 0`.

`num2` is computed with code in the spirit of the article you have cited. The use of `in` makes the run more efficient and there is no `gsort` (as in your code), which is quite slow. I have assumed that in each `group` there are no repeated dates:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
group str15 date count treat num
1 01.02.2000 1 1 2
1 01.06.2000 2 0 .
1 01.09.2000 3 0 .
1 01.11.2000 3 1 .
1 01.05.2002 4 0 .
1 01.01.2010 5 1 1
1 01.05.2010 6 0 .
2 01.01.2001 1 1 0
2 01.03.2002 2 1 0
end

list

gen date2 = date(date,"DMY")
format date2 %td
drop date count num

order date
list, sepby(group)


*----- what you want -----

gen num2 = .
isid group date, sort

forvalues j = 1/`=_N' {

    count in `j'/L if inrange(date2 - date2[`j'], 1, 365) & group == group[`j'] 

    replace num2 = r(N) in `j'
}

replace num2 = . if !treat

list, sepby(group)
```

`num3` is computed with code similar in spirit (and results) as that posted by @jfeigenbaum:

```
<snip>

*----- what you want -----

isid group date, sort
by group: gen indicat = sum(treat)

sort group indicat, stable
by group indicat: egen num3 = total(inrange(date2 - date2[1], 1, 365))
replace num3 = . if !treat

list, sepby(group)
```

Even more than two interpretations are possible for your problem, but I'll leave it at that.

(Note that I have changed your example data to include cases that probably make the problem more realistic.)

Comment: I am sorry for being imprecise! I hope I provied all missing information within a comment as a response to jfeigenbaum's post. Above that, I am going to edit my initial question with this information.

Comment: Seen against this background, observation with date 01nov2000 would have a value of 0 in variable treatment whereas observation with date 01may2002 would have a value of 1. Thus, the num3 column would be the one that meets my requirements (but only because treat = 1 observations cannot occur within this 1 year time frame). Again this is due to the lack of information i provided. Thank you for your effort, Roberto Ferrer!

Comment: Great. Thanks for providing feedback.