# Nearest Neighbor Matching in Stata

Tags: stata

I need to program a nearest neighbor algorithm in stata from scratch because my dataset does not allow me to use any of the available solutions (as far as I am concerned).

To be pecise. I have a dataset that is of similar structure to that of the following (original has around 14k observations)

```
input id value treatment match
1 0.14 0 .
2 0.32 0 .
3 0.465 1 2
4 0.878 1 2
5 0.912 1 2
6 0.001 1 1
end
```

I want to generate a variable called match (already included in the example above). For each observation with treatment == 1 the variable match should store the id of another observation from within treatment == 0 whose value is closest to value of the considered observation (treatment == 1).

I am new to stata programming, so I am not yet familiar with the syntax. My first shot is the following however it does not produce any changes to the match variable. I am sure this is a novice question but I am hoping for some advice on how to make the code running.

**EDIT**: I have changed the code slightly and now it seems to work. Do you see any problems that may arise if I run it on a bigger dataset?

```
set more off
clear all

input id pscore treatment
1 0.14 0
2 0.32 0
3 0.465 1
4 0.878 1
5 0.912 1
6 0.001 1
end

gen match = .

forval i = 1/`= _N' {
    if treatment[`i'] == 1 {

        local dist 1

        forvalues j = 1/`= _N' {
            if (treatment[`j'] == 0) {
                local current_dist (pscore[`i'] - pscore[`j'])^2

                if `dist' > `current_dist' {
                    local dist `current_dist' // update smallest distance
                    replace match = id[`j'] in `i' // write match

                }

            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: That's a bold undertaking. At a glance it seems likely that confusion between the `if` command and the `if` qualifier will bite you hard. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/index.html  You need explicit subscripting within the loop. Setting the loop to run over all the observations doesn't have any implications within the loop. There are other bugs too. I don't think the forum really extends to code review of complete programs by learners. Questions here are best focused on one difficulty at a time.

Comment: Why do you think that your dataset does not allow you to use any of the available solutions? What are those available solutions?

Comment: I don't know much Stata programming either but shouldn't the statement `if (treatment == 0)` be ```if (treatment[`j'] == 0)```? You're indexing sometimes but not other times.

Comment: If you're looking for propensity score matching, it is now built into Stata 13: http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/stata_psmatch.htm and there are also multiple third-party modules that can do it for you: https://kb.iu.edu/d/avll

Comment: @NickCox I have updated the code in my original post. It does seem to work though I have not applied it yet to my bigger dataset. Are the bugs that you identified in my initial code still in the current one? Is anything likely not to work for bigger datasets?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I have looked into the nearstat command which only seems to work on higher dimensions as far as I am concerned (geographical neighbors). Well, I guess I could somehow tweak my dataset to apply this command but I chose not do because an own solution seemed not to be that much of work.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: The psmatch2 command (I'm using stata13 which is why I cannot use this new command as of now) does the propensity score matching as well as the estimation of ATT all at once. Due to the dataset I am facing I need to do that in several steps so I need to apply my own solution (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: Might be some syntax help here: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-03/msg00525.html

Comment: The problem I see with that code is time to execute, which will depend ultimately on the size of the real data set. I have provided an answer regarding that issue, although you have not provided any visible feedback on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817366/count-observations-within-dynamic-range. It is not good practice to leave questions hanging when answers have been provided. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If no answer satisfies your original request, you can always leave an appreciative comment explaining why that is the case.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I was definately going to respond within a reasonable period of time, however it takes a while to understand the code, apply it to my original dataset and evaluate the performance. Thank you though for this reminder! Sorry for leaving you without a response until today!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider some simulated data: 1,000 observations, 200 of them untreated (`treat == 0`) and the rest treated (`treat == 1`). Then the code included below will be much more efficient than the originally posted. (Ties, like in your code, are not explicitly handled.)

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 1000
set seed 32956

gen id = _n
gen pscore = runiform()
gen treat = cond(_n <= 200, 0, 1)

*----- new method -----

timer clear
timer on 1

// get id of last non-treated and first treated
// (data is sorted by treat and ids are consecutive)
bysort treat (id): gen firsttreat = id[1]
local firstt = first[_N]
local lastnt = `firstt' - 1

// start loop
gen match = .
gen dif = .

quietly forvalues i = `firstt'/`=_N' {

    // compute distances
    replace dif = (pscore[`i'] - pscore)^2
    summarize dif in 1/`lastnt', meanonly

    // identify id of minimum-distance observation
    replace match = . in 1/`lastnt'
    replace match = id in 1/`lastnt' if dif == r(min)
    summarize match in 1/`lastnt', meanonly

    // save the minimum-distance id
    replace match = r(max) in `i'

}

// clean variable and drop
replace match = . in 1/`lastnt'
drop dif firsttreat

timer off 1

tempfile first
save `first'

*----- your method -----

drop match

timer on 2

gen match = .

quietly forval i = 1/`= _N' {
    if treat[`i'] == 1 {

        local dist 1

        forvalues j = 1/`= _N' {
            if (treat[`j'] == 0) {
                local current_dist (pscore[`i'] - pscore[`j'])^2

                if `dist' > `current_dist' {
                    local dist `current_dist' // update smallest distance
                    replace match = id[`j'] in `i' // write match

                }

            }
        }
    }   

}

timer off 2

tempfile second
save `second'

// check for equality of results
cf _all using `first'

// check times
timer list
```

The results in seconds to finish execution:

```
. timer list
   1:      0.19 /        1 =       0.1930
   2:     10.79 /        1 =      10.7900
```

The difference is huge, specially considering this data set has only 1,000 observations.

An interesting thing to notice is that as the number of non-treated cases increases relative to the number of treated, then the original method improves, but never reaches the levels of efficiency of the new method. As an example, invert the number of cases, so there is now 800 untreated and 200 treated (change data setup to `gen treat = cond(_n <= 800, 0, 1)`). The result is

```
. timer list
   1:      0.07 /        1 =       0.0720
   2:      4.45 /        1 =       4.4470
```

You can see that the new method also improves and is still much faster. In fact, the relative difference is still the same.

Another way to do this is using `joinby` or `cross`. The problem is they temporarily expand (a lot) the size of your data base. In many cases, they are not feasible due to the hard limit Stata has on the number of possible observations (see `help limits`). You can find an example of `joinby` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19784222/2077064.

### Edit

If there's a large number of treated relative to untreated, your code suffers
because you go through the whole first loop many more times (due to the first `if`). 
Furthermore, going through 
that whole loop once, implies going through another loop that
has itself two `if` conditions, `_N` more times.
The opposite case in which there are few treated observations means that you go through the whole
first loop only in a small number of occasions, speeding up your code substantially.

The reason my code can maintain its efficiency is due to the use of `in`. This always 
offers speed gains over `if`. Stata will go directly to those observations with no
logical checking needed. Your problem provides an opportunity for that replacement
and it's wise to seize it.

If my code used `if` where `in` is in place, the results would be different. 
Your code would be faster for the
case in which there's a large number of untreated relative to treated, and again, that
is because in your code there would not be the need to go through the complete loop, 
requiring very little work; 
the first loop is short-circuited with the first `if`. For the opposite case,
my code would still dominate.

The key is to "separate" treated from untreated and work on each group using `in`.

Comment: So from my understanding the improvement in performance comes from the fact that your loop does not iterate over (unnecessary) observations that have a 0 in variable treatment. Apparently, applying bysort first outperforms iterating over those observations. I had the same idea but my implementation decreased the performance further. Thank you very much for your effort, Roberto Ferrer, this code will be less costly and I learned a lot!