# Counting observations under varying conditions in Stata

Tags: stata, matching

I have a large dataset that is of the following structure (here is an example):

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| id       date   treat   match   num     |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  1  01feb2000       1       2      2    |
|  1  01apr2000       0       .      .    |
|  1  01jan2002       1       3      1    |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  2  01mar2000       1       3      0    |
|  2  01may2000       0       .      .    |
|-----------------------------------------|
|  3  01dec2002       1       .      .    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

For each group identified by an `id` I have certain occurrences at certain dates. Each occurrence is either treatment or control. Each treatment observation is matched to a certain `id`. You can take `id`, `date`, `treat` and `match` variables as given.

My goal is to calculate the value of `num` for each treatment observation that actually has a match (there can be cases in which treatment observations have no match, see `id` 3). **The rule is to calculate the number of any occurrences in the matched `id` (disregarding whether it is treated or not) within one year starting from the date of the treated observations.**

Example: The very first treated observation is matched with `id` 2. `id` 2 has two observations within the next year after February 1st, 2000.

**Important:** First, the date of the first occurrence within a matched id will NEVER be before the date of the considered treatment observation. Second, several treatment observations can be matched with the same `id`.

Please be aware that a similar question has been asked here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817366/count-observations-within-dynamic-range). Here, I am concerned with the efficiency of the algorithm as my dataset is huge. My solution is the following:

```
gen NUM = .
gen yrafter = 25000    // arbitrary date outside of the panel
format yrafter %td
gen in_window = 0
sort id date

forval i = 1/`=_N' {
    if (match[`i'] != .) {
        replace yrafter = (date_installation[`i'] + 365) if ags == match[`i']
            replace in_window = date_installation <= yrafter & ags == match[`i']

            by id: egen NUM_temp = sum(in_window) if ags == match[`i']
            replace NUM_temp = 0 if NUM_temp == .
            sum NUM_temp if ags == match[`i'], meanonly

            replace NUM0 in `i' = r(max)
        drop NUM_temp

        replace in_window = 0 if ags == match[`i']
    }
}

drop yrafter in_window
```

To reduce the number of iterations I would actually like to sort after treatment observations and only iterate over them. However, in my understanding of the problem I cannot do this because some subsequent commands require the sorting I have applied above (am I right on this?).

My strategy is to iterate over each relevant observation: For all observations in the matched `id` group I replace the value of `yrafter` with the latest possible occurrence that needs to be considered. Then in the variable `in_window` I simply identify those observations that are before the latest possible date (remember, there cannot be any occurrences before the date of the `treatment` variable) and afterwards count all the ones. I save the result in `num` and set everything up for the next iteration.

Apparently, this requires a lot of time. My first guess would be to optimize the loop head because checking the `if` condition seems very time-consuming for Stata. Does anybody have an idea for optimization?

Comment: What can you say about the size of your data set? How many `id`s? Min, max and average number of observations per `id`? Total number of observations? Does your code provide correct results? How long does it take? PC specifications?

Comment: The size of my dataset exceeds 1 Mio. observation and around 14,000 id's. My code did provide correct results though I cannot provide you with any exact information on the run time at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
 id  str20 date   treat   match   num     
  1  01feb2000       1       2      2    
  1  01apr2000       0       .      .    
  1  01jan2002       1       3      1    
  2  01mar2000       1       3      0    
  2  01may2000       0       .      .    
  3  01dec2002       1       .      .    
end

list, sepby(id)

gen dat = date(date,"DMY")
format %td dat
drop date
order dat, after(id)

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

gen num2 = .
forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    if treat[`i'] == 1 {
        count if id == match[`i'] & dat <=  dat[`i'] + 365
        replace num2 = r(N) in `i'
    }
}
replace num2 = . if missing(match)

list, sepby(id)

assert num == num2
```

I have no information on the size of your data set, so unless you reveal that with precision, I won't do any testing.

(I did not check your code. I simply tried translating the wording of your problem to Stata code.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It appears to me that the fact that I did not know the count command made my life very difficult. I have tested the algorithm above on my original dataset: The results are correct and the run time is appropriate, i.e. much better than before (again, I did not take the exact run time). Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I would worry about efficiency only when I had correct code. The following are bugs.

- The test  `if (match != .)` reduces always to  `if (match[1] != .)`. Presumably you need to test each value in turn. http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/index.html may apply here.
- The statement

  ```
  replace NUM0 in `i' = r(max)
  ```

is illegal, and should be presumably be

```
    replace NUM0 = r(max) in `i'
```

I can't comment on your major question, as I don't understand what you are trying to do. I guess your explanation is clear and logical; it's just too complicated for me to absorb the whole of what you are doing when I never do anything similar.